# Misplaced view warning

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, constraints

My view position:

[image]

My constraints:

[image]

Last two constraints is equal to 0.

Warning:

"Vertical position will be 428 at run time but is 420 in the canvas."

Seems like a fake warning, because when I launch it, my button is on right place. How can i fix warning or hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove all the constraints and then put them back in.  It should work.  This happens sometimes when you place your constraints, then move the view by dragging on it by mistake.  It has happened to me before.  Click on your view and down at the bottom of the storyboard you have a couple of boxes.  One of them was for placing your constraints, the one next (to the right) to that has an option to remove all constrain on the view.  As long as the view is selected you will remove them all on just the view.  Then put them back in the way you want and the warning will go away.  You may have just nudged the view a bit without knowing.  Let us know if this works.

EDIT #1

That is pretty strange.  I have followed my directions in a sample project and things worked out fine.  No warnings.  However, I noticed that your lower constraint you said was 0.  Look at my picture it is actually 88.

[image]

I think you need to choose bottom layout guide when you select the lower constraint.  I don't know why yours would come out as zero.  Give it a go and let us know.

Comment: Thanks. I sure, that it will work. And now I'm sure, that constraints a bit bugged atm.

Comment: It works, but i got one more problem. When I add new constraint warning appears again almost each time. So I need to readd each constraint 8-10 times. Still dont know how to fix it.

Comment: @Kenarius1, check out my EDIT #1.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on the warning, it will give you the option to reposition the view to match the constraints, and another to adjust the constraints to match the view’s current position. You shouldn’t have to delete and re-add the constraints unless you are doing something really complicated.

As [Douglas said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23346226/255489), this state occurs if you have moved the view or set the constraints to values that do not match the current position of the view. The Interface Builder UI will typically not move views without your permission, but when you run the app, the constraints are evaluated without reference to how your views are positioned in the xib/storyboard.

Comment: I can't activate this option to reposition the view to match the constraints.  Either the parent "Misplaced View" or the "Size will be..." opened with the disclosure arrow.  Clicking just highlights the warning.  No option to resize.  XCode 5.1.1

Comment: Are you sure you’re clicking in the right place? [Apple documentation on this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html)

Comment: I was not!  "In the Interface Builder outline view. If there are any issues in the top-level view that you’re editing on the canvas, the Interface Builder outline view shows a disclosure arrow."  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you have to select your interface builder then go to editor panel->Resolve Auto Layout Issue->Update Frame and you will be done.It worked for me.Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

New `Xcode` version has a button called

Update frames (the first button from the right in the debug Area)

it will update view `constraint` if you dragged or repositioned it by mistake to the actual constraint.

[image]